# Does Appium supports native or web apps on Iphone in windows OS?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, selenium, appium

I am currently using selenium webdrivers for web application automation. Planning to develop tests for Native and web apps in Iphone.

I was wondering if I could use Appium to test both android and IOS. And we are working on Windows machines currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Appium to test both Android and iOS apps, both native and web based.

In terms of what platforms are supported:

- for iOS test automation:

  - Mac OS X 10.7 or higher, 10.8.4 recommended
  - XCode >= 4.6.3
  - Apple Developer Tools (iPhone simulator SDK, command line tools)
- for Android test automation:

  - OS X, Linux and has **beta support for Windows**
  - Android SDK API >= 17

Here's a link with more info and instructions - check out Requirements section:
http://appium.io/getting-started.html